# How to show column names when you in different catalog in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose there are 2 catalogs. First is 'master', second is 'test'. I want to see columns of test catalog's tables when my current catalog is master.

There is command is like:

```
SELECT
    sys.columns.name AS ColumnName
FROM
    sys.columns
JOIN 
    sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
```

This command getting current schemas columns. It means I have to change my catalog master to test. Is there any way to show columns without `USE test` command?

Comment: Just use `[test].[sys].[columns]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 3-part name:

```
SELECT c.name AS ColumnName
FROM master.sys.columns c
JOIN master.sys.tables t 
  ON c.object_id = t.object_id
UNION ALL
SELECT c.name AS ColumnName
FROM test.sys.columns c
JOIN test.sys.tables t 
  ON c.object_id = t.object_id
```